# How create a mobile app with python and static web (html, css and js)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, mobile

I'm searching for a way to create a python desktop gui program, and in the search I find the package named '[eel](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel)' and I liked how it works, because the visual application is made with html, css and javascript. It create a desktop application, so I'm with this question: have a way to create a mobile application, like we can do with kivy, using html, javascript and css?

Comment: You should try looking at [progressive web apps](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/).

Comment: Wow, I doesn't know this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out progressive web applications, they may interest you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app
https://web.dev/learn/pwa/

example with Django (first article found by me in the Internet)
https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/convert-django-website-to-a-progressive-web-app-3536bc4f2862

example with flask (also first article found in the Internet)
https://medium.com/@tristan_4694/how-to-create-a-progressive-web-app-pwa-using-flask-f227d5854c49

Also as far as I know Toga allows you to use html and css for styling.
https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Really? I don't know the name 'progressive web app'. I already know the Django and Flask for web development, but I doesn't know that they can be used to mobile app. But I doesn't know the Toga package, and I search and I think amazing, thank you!

Comment: Sorry if my question looks fool, but I really don't know much about mobile development.